# getJSON not returning anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The JSON function below is not returning anything...

```
$.getJSON(formUrl, function(data) {
                alert(data)
              $('.response').html('<p>' + data.title + '</p>'
                + '<p>' + data.description + '</p>');
            });
```

the formUrl is correct and returning data in the form of

```
{"title":"Smashing Magazine","description":"Smashing Magazine is focused on design and web-development. We deliver useful information, latest trends and techniques, useful ideas, innovative approaches and tools."}
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I'm alerting the data and its empty as well...

Thanks!

Comment: What does PHP had to do with this ? I changed the tags now.

Comment: Not to be the Tag Police, but if your code is heavily JQuery based then you should tag it as such as a courtesy.

Answer (score 3):

Are you calling `$.getJSON` with a cross-domain URL (ie. from localhost to somewhere else)? That won't work unless you use the JSONP dataType.

Comment: its on my localhost but i'm referring to it absolutely.. 

ie. formUrl = "http://localhost:8888/NewMT/tools/fetch.php?url=" + $(this).val,

would this affect it?

Comment: I believe cross-port access don't work either. Are you serving your page from localhost:8888 aswell?

Comment: Yes, changed port is not Same Origin, so because of the Same Origin Policy, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not of the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you need to add the [`Access-Control`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) headers to the JSON response.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not break the string in two lines, it will result in error and may be the reason of Javascript not running.

Try something like this: (Notice how I did not break the content inside html() in two lines)

```
$.getJSON(formUrl, function(data) {
                alert(data);
              $('.response').html('<p>' + data.title + '</p>' + '<p>' + data.description + '</p>');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure your server to deliver the page `fetch.php` with a contentType `application/json`

Also just for a test, you can try to put your JSON into a `.../fetch.js` file and call it with `$.getJSON`.
It should work, as .js files are `application/javascript` by default on most servers.